# Problem with interpreting route resource type for the RelatedPeople model

Tags: vue.js, axios, laravel-7

Hypothesis: I think it is the pluralization of resource or model, I am not sure.

**My code:**

Route web:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> 'auth'], function() {  
    Route::resource('relatedPersons', 'RelatedPeople\RelatedPeopleController')
    ->only(['store','update','destroy'])
    ->middleware('can:relatedPeoples');
});
```

**Note:** the model is relatedPeople, but for testing purposes in the definition of the route leave it like this relatedPersons.

RelatedPeople(Model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RelatedPeople extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'phone',
        'email', 
        'detail',
        'case_report_id'
    ];
    
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:m');
    }

    public function getDetailAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value ?? "Sin detalle.";
    }
}
```

RelatedPeopleController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\RelatedPeople;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\RelatedPeople;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RelatedPeopleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'email'=> "required|unique:related_people"
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $relatedPeople = RelatedPeople::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($relatedPeople, 200);
    }
}
```

Frontend vuejs with axios:

```
onSubmit() {
    let formData = new FormData(this.$refs.create)
    formData.append('case_report_id', this.case_id)
    axios.post('relatedPersons', formData).then( (response) => {
        if ( response.status == 200 ) {
            this.$emit('addRelatedPerson', response.data)
            this.$toasterE.success("Related people create", { mark:1 })
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.$refs.form.reset()
                this.form = form()
            });
        }
    }).catch( (err) => {
        this.exception(err)
    })
}
```

The above code every time I run it goes into the catch and returns this error:
{"error": "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.", "code": 405}

Tests I've already done:

1. change resource name
2. In the model add table name protected $ table = "related_people"
3. Define a get (index) method to the controller to know that at least the request reaches the controller and only the GET method works, the rest do not work.

I will keep looking for a solution, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after almost exploding my head I found that it was a mistake that the solution is in my face, not in my turquoise eyes but in front of my face.

**The solution is:**

Frontend vuejs with axios( **before** ):

```
onSubmit() {
    let formData = new FormData(this.$refs.create)
    formData.append('case_report_id', this.case_id)
    axios.post('relatedPersons', formData).then( (response) => {
        if ( response.status == 200 ) {
            this.$emit('addRelatedPerson', response.data)
            this.$toasterE.success("Related people create", { mark:1 })
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.$refs.form.reset()
                this.form = form()
            });
        }
    }).catch( (err) => {
        this.exception(err)
    })
}
```

Frontend vuejs with axios( **solved** ):

```
onSubmit() {
    let formData = new FormData(this.$refs.create)
    formData.append('case_report_id', this.case_id)
    axios.post('/relatedPersons', formData).then( (response) => {
        if ( response.status == 200 ) {
            this.$emit('addRelatedPerson', response.data)
            this.$toasterE.success("Related people create", { mark:1 })
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.$refs.form.reset()
                this.form = form()
            });
        }
    }).catch( (err) => {
        this.exception(err)
    })
}
```

If you haven't seen it yet, it's the route definition '/relatedPersons'

```
axios.post('/relatedPersons', formData).then( (response) => {
```

Now because of this problem, suppose I access the path axios.post('relatedPeoples', data) and the url of the application is test.dev/cases/1, the result of the request would be test.dev/cases/relatedPeoples and here the problem.

laravel tells me if the route exists but that method is not supported.

I hope my mistake helps many.